# Example of discontinous effect of x on y dataset (for paper)

Tags: dataset, regression-discontinuity

For a paper, I need an example of a dataset $(x_i,y_i)$ where the residuals are $iid$ (the $x$ do not represent time) with a discontinuity on the effect of $x$ on $y$.

- I have already found a dataset in [Berger and Pope](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/devinpope.pdf) 2010 but the jump there is not clearly visible
- The 'LifeCycleSavings' dataset has been suggested, but it has only 50 observations (ideally, I would be looking at 100).

Does anyone know of other datasets?

Comment: The variates cannot possibly be iid if there is any effect at all.  Presumably you mean there is a function $f$ such that $y_i - f(x_i)$ are iid conditional on the $x_i$ (or some such thing) and where $f$ has a discontinuity.

Comment: yes. Corrected.

Comment: See the genetic sequences at http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~mueller/changetrees.pdf (at the end).  A dataset of 56 cases where a slope exhibits a discontinuous jump is given at http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect048.htm .  Googling "multivariate changepoint problem dataset -time" yields promising hits.

Comment: Thank you @WHuber, the google keyword you suggested lead me to examples from a problem i did not know of. Can you post your comment as an answer (Snijders and al 2001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In economics, this is called "regression discontinuity." For one example, check out

David Card & Carlos Dobkin & Nicole Maestas, 2008. "The Impact of Nearly Universal Insurance Coverage on Health Care Utilization: Evidence from Medicare," American Economic Review, American Economic Association, vol. 98(5), pages 2242-58. [[data](http://www.e-aer.org/data/dec08/20051296_data.zip)]

Here's a summary piece:

Lee, David S., and Thomas Lemieux. 2010. "Regression Discontinuity Designs in Economics." Journal of Economic Literature, 48(2): 281–355. [[article page](http://www.aeaweb.org/articles.php?doi=10.1257/jel.48.2.281)]

Hope that helps.